# Auditoria com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou querendo fazer as tabelas de auditoria das minhas entidades. A princípio eu pensei em sobrescrever o método `SaveChanges`. Também pensei em escrever um método que vai estar fazendo a auditoria em meu `repository` base. Usando das duas formas, eu terei uma única tabela de auditoria para todo o meu sistema.

Mas por questões de performance eu preciso que cada entidade tenha sua tabela de log.

Qual seria a melhor forma para interceptar o tipo da minha entidade para que eu possa salvar na tabela de auditoria da mesma?

Meu código até então, está assim:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
     var entriesAdicionadas = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

     var entriesModificadas = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

     var entriesDeletadas = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();
     foreach (var entry in entriesAdicionadas)
     {

     }
     int result = base.SaveChanges();

     foreach (var entry in entriesModificadas)
     {
         var nome = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
     }

     base.SaveChanges();

     foreach (var entry in entriesDeletadas)
     {
         var nome = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
     }

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Implementação Caseira

Primeiro você precisa criar uma maneira de relacionar o *Model* de Log com o *Model* que será auditado. Isso pode ser feito declarando uma *Model* com genérico. Por exemplo:

```
public class ModelDeLogGenerico<T>
    where T: class
{

}
```

`T` não precisa ser `class`. `T` pode ser uma classe ancestral de todos os seus *Models*, ou então uma interface. Em alguns projetos que eu faço, todos os *Models* derivam de uma interface chamada `IEntityBase`, em que forço o *Model* a ter duas propriedades a mais: na primeira registro a data em que o registro foi criado e na segunda a data em que ele foi modificado pela última vez, que é mais ou menos assim:

```
namespace MyProject.Models.Interfaces
{
    interface IEntityBase
    {
        DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Isto garante que seu *Model* de Log não pode receber necessariamente qualquer classe. A classe pra ser válida precisa implementar `IEntityBase`. Minha classe de Log, portanto, ficaria assim:

```
public class ModelDeLogGenerico<T>
    where T: IEntityBase
{

}
```

Suponha agora um *Model* qualquer do seu sistema:

```
public class Fruta 
{
    ...
}
```

O Log respectivo dele será:

```
public class LogFruta<Fruta>
{
    ...
}
```

Tendo isso, podemos identificar agora que `LogFruta` audita `Fruta`. O seguinte código baseado em Reflection busca no Assembly da sua aplicação qual classe possui como argumento genérico a classe `Fruta`:

```
var log = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0] == entry.GetType());
```

## Soluções Prontas

O [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) possui capacidade nativa de fazer o log pra você. [Tem uma explicação aqui](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Audit-Log).